# Stateful SOAP webservice example

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client, soa

I am trying to do a POC where i need to invoke a Stateful SOAP webservice . I need to do a login call first to SOAP webservice and get the session id(or cookie or something like that) and use the session id  for making subsequent calls to the webservice . I want to know if there is any sample stateful SOAP webservice hosted on the internet for which i can generate the client and try invoking the webservice to verify Stateful operation. Any other pointers on how i can do this is also very welcome.

If this POC is successful we will be invoking a Stateful SOAP webservice hosted by one of our vendors and we will be using a TIBCO BW client to call the SOAP webservice.

Comment: Stateful or Stateless SOAP webservice call is just like any another web-service call. In your case, since you have to get the response of the first webservice call and use it in the subsequent calls, I think you should focus on how would you cache the cookie/token that you receive from the first call. Also, if there is an expire to the token received, what would be your technique of refreshing the token.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the WebServiceDefinitionLanguage from the WSDL attached in the [link](http://www.stgregorioschurchdc.org/wsdl/Bible.wsdl) It brings encouraging quotes. 
You may use SOAP activity in BW or import the WSDL as a resource first and then use any SOAP or web service activity.

Check this java project in [github](https://github.com/aleon1220/multi-cloud-AttendWebApp) is a multi cloud java project that invokes WebServices and Rest services from many Cloud providers and Many sites. It gives you an idea on how to do it.

Of course in BW is really easy to do it. Basically: start activity, SOAP activity, log, call subprocess, catch errors, end process.

Answer (score 0):

Stateful or Stateless SOAP webservice call is just like any another web-service call. In your case, since you have to get the response(i.e. receiving token) of the first webservice call and use it in the subsequent calls, I think you should focus on how would you cache the cookie/token that you receive from the first call. Also, if there is an expiry associated to the life of the token received in your response, work on the technique of refreshing the token for which the SOAP API provider will have to provide you an token expiry interval.